# Springboot App: Consider defining a bean of type in your configuration

Tags: java, spring

Im trying to start a springboot application. But when it's starting, i get an error message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in spring_boot.controller.RekeningController required a bean of type 'spring_boot.mappers.RekeningMapper' that could not be found.

Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'spring_boot.mappers.RekeningMapper' in your configuration.
```

I tried to add the @Bean annotation in the RekeningMapper, but thats works not as wel. I search everywhere on the internet but i can't find a solution.

Below I have placed the code that it affects.

RekeningMapper

```
package spring_boot.mappers;

//Imports

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface RekeningMapper {

    RekeningDto naarRekeningDto(Rekening rekening);
    Rekening naarRekeningModel(RekeningDto rekeningDto);
    
    @Mapping(source = "rekeningen", target = "rekeningenIDs")
    RekeningHouderDto naarRekeningHouderDto(RekeningHouder rekeningHouder);
    RekeningHouder naarRekeningHouderModel(RekeningHouderDto rekeningHouderDto);
    
    default List<String> rekeningToRekeningIds(List<Rekening> rekeningen) {
        List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (Rekening rek : rekeningen)
            ids.add(rek.getRekening_id());
        
        return ids;
    }
}
```

RekeningController

```
package spring_boot.controller;

// Imports

@RestController
@RequestMapping("rekeningen")
public class RekeningController {
    
    private RekeningService rekeningService;
    private final RekeningMapper rekeningMapper;
    
    @Autowired
    public RekeningController(RekeningService rekeningService, RekeningMapper rekeningMapper) {
        this.rekeningMapper = rekeningMapper;
        this.rekeningService = rekeningService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<RekeningDto>> getAllRekeningen() {
        List<Rekening> rekeningen = this.rekeningService.getAllRekeningen();
        List<RekeningDto> rekeningDtos = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (Rekening rekening : rekeningen) 
            rekeningDtos.add(rekeningMapper.naarRekeningDto(rekening));
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok(rekeningDtos);
    }
}
```

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Are you using maven or gradle? You need to share your dependencies also

Comment: @DanielJacob i added the dependencies. I use maven

Comment: I don't think this is your complete pom. I don't see mapstruct in there and you also need to define a plugin section.

Comment: It seems you didn't add mapstruct  annotation processor as in @Daniel Jacob answer. I deleted it in my project and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your dependencies and mapstruct processor plugin need to look like this. Update the source and target to the java version you are using. Also make sure that your project is using Java 1.8 or later (project properties →
"Java Compiler" → "Compile Compliance Level"). It will not work with older
versions.

```
<properties>
    <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.0.CR1</org.mapstruct.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
       <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
       <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
          <path>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
          </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
     </configuration>
   </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

Furthermore To double check that everything is working as expected, go to your project’s properties and select "Java Compiler" → "Annotation Processing" → "Factory Path".
The MapStruct processor JAR should be listed and enabled there